# Structured Streaming to Save JSON to HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

My Structured Spark Streaming program is to read JSON data from Kafka
and write to HDFS in JSON format.  I am able to save JSON to HDFS but
it saves the JSON string with:

```
 "jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))"
key as below: {"jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))":{"age":42,"name":"John"}}.
```

How to save only

```
{"age":42,"name":"John"}?




StructType schema = kafkaPrimerRow.schema();

//Read json from kafka. JSON is: {"age":42,"name":"John"}
Dataset<Row> df = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .format("kafka")
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", input_bootstrap_server)
                    .option("subscribe", topics[0])
                    .load();




    //Save Stream to HDFS
    StreamingQuery ds = df             
.select(functions.from_json(col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType),schema)) 
.writeStream()

.format("json")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.option("path", destPath)
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following .select("data.*") did the trick.

```
StreamingQuery ds = df
                        .select(functions.from_json(col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType),schema).as("data"))
                        .select("data.*")
                        .writeStream()
                        .format("json")
                        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                        .option("path", destPath)
                        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
                        .start();
```